# How do i enable Prometheus/Grafana to show my rabbitmq metrics ? It currently shows no data

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator

I am using the prometheus-community stack.

I have a rabbitmq pod running in my K8s cluster, I have enabled rabbitmq_prometheus from within the pod so I am able to see the time series data of of my rabbitmq from localhost:15692. I have also installed a dashboard in grafana (this [enter link description here](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10991)) in order to be able to see this data. However I get No Data showing in my RabbitMQ dashboard. as shown below. [image].

I have also installed prometheus-community/prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter, saved the values file locally so that i can make changes to it, currently it looks like this below

```
prometheus:
  monitor:
    enabled: true
    additionalLabels: {}
    interval: 15s
    namespace: []
  rules:
    enabled: false
    additionalLabels: {}
```

I have applied the values file to my helm release however when i do an inspect on it, i still get **enabled: false** I am not sure what I am missing or doing wrong.

How do i show my rabbitmq metrics in grafana ?

Comment: How did you install prometheus? If via helm, can you share values file for that. How you installed rabbitmq? How did you enable rabbitmq_prometheus?

Comment: yes, via helm and i have already enabled rabbitmq_prometheus @rock'nrolla

Comment: Can you please share configuration/values file for prometheus & rabbitmq and command you used to enable rabbitmq_prometheus? It's to look for any possible misconfigurations and reproduce the error.

Comment: @rock'nrolla to enable rabbitmq metrics, i ran the command rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_prometheus and this allows me to see the metrics on port 15692

Comment: @rock'nrolla also prometheus  I installed with Helm is from the Prometheus-Community github channel so the configs are still the default values.

Answer (score 4):

I've not really understood the steps you took to make it work, but I understand your problem is not being able to import RabbitMQ metrics in Prometheus. So here's the solution.

1.Deploy prometheus using `kube-prometheus-stack` [helm chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack). As the helm chart comes with "prometheus operator", it's best to use PodMonitor and/or ServiceMonitor CRD's as they provide far more configuration options. [Here's](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#include-servicemonitors) some documentation around that.

Keep default values (as the purpose is just to import RabbitMQ metrics) for most of the stuff, except that set  `"prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelector.matchLabels"` with a label value. Something like this

```
serviceMonitorSelector:
  matchLabels:
    monitoring-platform: core-prometheus
```

2.Deploy RabbitMQ using the bitnami rabbitmq [helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq). Again, as the purpose here is just to expose metrics for prometheus to scrape, you can use default values for much of it. Here's the values file:

```
## Prometheus Metrics
metrics:
  enabled: true
  plugins: 'rabbitmq_prometheus'
  podAnnotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/port: '{{ .Values.service.metricsPort }}'

  ## Prometheus Service Monitor
  ## ref: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    interval: 30s
    additionalLabels:
      monitoring-platform: core-prometheus
```

So using the `serviceMonitor` label (which matches the label of prometheus `serviceMonitorSelector`) Prometheus identifies RabbitMQ as a target.

[image: prometheus-target]

[image: grafana-rabbitmq-dashboard]