# RabbitMQ targets not visible in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, prometheus

I have a RabbitMQ cluster deployed on Kubernetes **using the kubectl rabbitmq plugin** by following this guide (https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/quickstart-operator.html)

Prometheus was deployed on same Kubernetes cluster in 'monitoring' namespace using **kube-prometheus-stack helm chart** (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack)

And then I followed https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/operator-monitoring.html to connect RabbitMQ to Prometheus.

Prometheus & Grafana works fine, but I'm not able to see any entry for RabbitMQ in Targets section of Prometheus UI like it's mentioned here:
[image]

Targets page is only showing Prometheus related stuff. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you share the servicemonitor yaml that's created for RabbitMQ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i enable Prometheus/Grafana to show my rabbitmq metrics ? It currently shows no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67006873/how-do-i-enable-prometheus-grafana-to-show-my-rabbitmq-metrics-it-currently-sh)

Comment: @vjdhama I'm using this as it is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/main/observability/prometheus/monitors/rabbitmq-servicemonitor.yml

Comment: @rock'nrolla in your linked post, what do I for 2nd step since I'm not using bitnami helm charts for RabbitMQ? Also, [rabbitmq-servicemonitor.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/main/observability/prometheus/monitors/rabbitmq-servicemonitor.yml) mentions "If labels are defined in spec.serviceMonitorSelector.matchLabels of your deployed Prometheus object, make sure to include them here". That seems like a different structure than the one mentioned in linked post.

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned in that .yml file as well as here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/blob/main/observability/prometheus/monitors/README.md#prometheus-scrape-targets
Check the `matchLabels` of your Prometheus spec, you would need to add the same `label` to the `PodMonitor` & `ServiceMonitor` objects.

BTW, using the rabbitmq helm chart (as well) will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this entire thing working!

If you are following [this guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/operator-monitoring.html) and got stuck somewhere just like me, just throw it out and take a look at [this bash script](https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/blob/main/observability/quickstart.sh) instead. I don't know if their guide is outdated, but there's a lot of missing or obscured info that's actually present in the above bash script.

Comment: I don't think the guide there is outdated or worthy of "throwing it out" as you mentioned. The guide which you are referring to points to the configuration needed to export your metrics to prometheus but not how you configure prometheus in the first place.

Comment: The script which you followed sets `ruleSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false`, `prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false`, `prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false`, `prometheus.prometheusSpec.probeSelectorNilUsesHelmValues=false`
which basically sets all 4 of those to {} and thus covers a much wider range of podMonitors, serviceMonitors etc.

Look at this condition: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/kube-prometheus-stack-36.2.0/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/prometheus.yaml#L145

Comment: That script basically allowed you to fix your problem but not necessarily improved knowledge to understand what exactly fixed it.

Comment: @rock'nrolla That's true. But I had already spent way too many hours trying to go through it to get it working, and had to wrap it up quickly since deadline was approaching. If someone writes a guide for something, I expect it to at least get me started with a basic working example and not make me spend hours troubleshooting it. The bash script does exactly that. You can just check out later what each configuration does and further modify it according to your setup.

Comment: Also, maybe the guide works for others and it's just me who's facing the issue - which is why I wrote "...following this guide and got stuck somewhere just like me..." 